# Is there a CLI tool that would prettify a JSON string

Tags: centos, text-formatting, software-rec, json

On my host I enter the following, which returns a bunch of information which isn't particularly easy to read at the CLI.

`echo $ENV_VAR | base64 --decode`

Is there a way to format it?

This is a sample output from the command.

> {"something": [{"path": "something", "host": "something.internal",
>   "scheme": "solr", "port": 8080, "ip": "123.4.567.89"}],
>   "second_database": [{"username": "user", "password": "", "ip":
>   "123.4.567.89", "host": "second_database.internal", "query":
>   {"is_master": true}, "path": "main", "scheme": "mysql", "port":
>   3306}], "redis": [{"ip": "123.4.567.89", "host": "redis", "scheme":
>   "redis", "port": 6379}], "database": [{"username": "user", "password":
>   "", "ip": "123.4.567.89", "host": "database.internal", "query":
>   {"is_master": true}, "path": "main", "scheme": "mysql", "port":
>   3306}]}

It's probably worth pointing out that my host, like many, offers a read-only file system.

Comment: There are thousands of ways to format some text. At least give the input (i.e. the output from `base64 --decode` and the desired format, including preferred tools used for formatting that (so I don't come up with some Haskell based solution where you only can fine tune things in Occam.

Comment: Yes, but depends entirely on what the decoded content looks like.

Comment: What are you accessing to inspect this value, any chance you do part of that decode on your local machine with e.g. something like  `ssh user@remote "echo $ENV_VAR | base64 --decode" | yaml from-json -`

Comment: @Anthon The accepted answer works without writing a file or any installs.

Comment: @crmpicco I can only hope ruamel.yaml at some time comes pre-installed on hosted machines. I am working on it to get to that level

Comment: @Anthon It certainly looks impressive.

Comment: @StehenKitt How exactly is that _too broad_ ?!?

Comment: A good and complete answer to a closely related question can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-in-a-shell-script

Comment: I think this question should be reopened. I could not find a tool in the Linux commands, but there is an npm package for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify You can install it with the npm command in nodejs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
cat file.json | json_pp  #perl utility
cat file.json | jq .
```

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) packs much more than just pretty-printing abilities.

Comment: (I know that I abuse cats and I don't care.)

Comment: Sadly I don't have a file (read-only file system). What I have to work from is the output from the `echo` command I gave in my question.

Comment: `echo "$your_json" | ...`

Comment: You don't need cat for jq, `jq . file.json` works just as well.

Comment: @k0pernikus Yeah. or `< file.json theCommand`. The performance overhead of `cat` probably doesn't matter here, and the `cat` version has some syntactic advantages. Everything's a tradeoff. Taste plays a role too.

Answer (score 2):

I would pipe that into `yaml`  (which is part of [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) of which I am the author):

```
echo $ENV_VAR | base64 --decode | yaml from-json -
```

will give you this (based on your example output):

```
second_database:
- username: user
  password: ''
  ip: 123.4.567.89
  host: second_database.internal
  path: main
  query:
    is_master: true
  scheme: mysql
  port: 3306
redis:
- ip: 123.4.567.89
  host: redis
  scheme: redis
  port: 6379
something:
- path: something
  host: something.internal
  scheme: solr
  port: 8080
  ip: 123.4.567.89
database:
- username: user
  password: ''
  ip: 123.4.567.89
  host: database.internal
  path: main
  query:
    is_master: true
  scheme: mysql
  port: 3306
```

The ordering of the keys is not guaranteed, because it is not guaranteed in json and I don't have a `ruamel.json` package like `ruamel.yaml` that preserves order when reading in `json`.

The above works on the principle that YAML is a superset of JSON, but has more readable display modes (leaving out quotes when not absolutely necessary, making indented block structure).

Comment: I thought that you could pipe directly into `yaml` I have to check why that is not working. Until then you would need to write a temporary file. `yaml` writes to stdout

Comment: Thanks, the format that you have given here is exactly what i'm looking for. Unfortunately I need a CLI tool that doesn't require writing to the file system as my host offers only a read-only file system...and `yaml` is not installed.

Comment: I fixed the "piping" in ruamel.yaml-0.9.8, but you would still need to install that on the system ( `pip install ruamel.yaml`)

Answer (score 1):

OK, that output is JSON. So parse as JSON:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl;
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

local $/; 
print to_json ( decode_json ( <> ), {pretty => 1 });
```

Will print your thing as:

```
{
   "something" : [
      {
         "host" : "something.internal",
         "scheme" : "solr",
         "ip" : "123.4.567.89",
         "path" : "something",
         "port" : 8080
      }
   ],
   "second_database" : [
      {
         "path" : "main",
         "ip" : "123.4.567.89",
         "query" : {
            "is_master" : true
         },
         "host" : "second_database.internal",
         "port" : 3306,
         "password" : "",
         "scheme" : "mysql",
         "username" : "user"
      }
   ],
   "redis" : [
      {
         "scheme" : "redis",
         "ip" : "123.4.567.89",
         "port" : 6379,
         "host" : "redis"
      }
   ],
   "database" : [
      {
         "username" : "user",
         "password" : "",
         "scheme" : "mysql",
         "port" : 3306,
         "host" : "database.internal",
         "ip" : "123.4.567.89",
         "query" : {
            "is_master" : true
         },
         "path" : "main"
      }
   ]
}
```

Formatted, and for bonus points - still JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Try `echo $ENV_VAR | base64 --decode | json_reformat`. If this is a 6.x or higher Centos version, you should have it

Answer (score 0):

The following npmjs package does the task: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify

You can install it with

```
npm -g install js-beautify
```

globally, although overwriting the debian packages is baaaad practice. Better if you create your own global or local package set and use the tool from that.

You need nodejs for that.